# Обмен данными между классами в угловом

Tags: angular2, typescript

Просьба не смеяться, я слабоват, не могу осилить логику работы тайпскриптов. Попробую объяснить что не получается комментариями в скрипте.
Ниже я пытаюсь: объединить модуль обращения к апи за проверкой авторизации и модуль роутера.

```
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


@NgModule({
    providers: [ UserService, Test ]
  })


// Так я обращаюсь к апи в модулях компонентов
export class Test {

    user: any;

    constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.userService.getUser().subscribe(data => {
          this.user = data;
          // Здесь происходит обращение к АПИ, который возвращает логин или false
          // Присваиваем переменной auth значение (конечно это не работает, здесь нужна помощь)
          if(this.user['login'] != false) {$auth = true;}
        });

    }
}


// Это текущий модуль, который должен отправить на форму входа со страниц, требующих авторизации
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean> | boolean{

        // Здесь надо получить переменную auth из класса Test
        if($auth) {return true;} else {location('/login');}
    }
```

Comment: $auth - это что?

Answer (score 0):

Собственно так работать не будет. Вот краткий, примерный сценарий:

1. Необходим сервис авторизации. В нем реализовывается метод авторизации и свойство, сигнализирующее что вы авторизованы.
2. Пути должны быть организованы так: Корень, от корня идут незащищённые пути (Логин, Страница ошибки и т.д) и защищенный путь, а корень которого вещается `Guard`.
3. Необходим `Guard` который вещается на защищенный корневой роут приложения, в котором проверяется, авторизованы вы или нет. Если ен авторизованы, то бросает на страницу логина.
4. Страница логина, реализует вход, инжектирует в себя сервис авторизации. Вызывает метод авторизации сервиса, который авторизируется в системе и устанавливает флаг, о том что вы авторизированны.

Далее уже усложнение логики в свете способов авторизации. Я их уже расписывать не буду.